# c++ templates implementing on structures

Tags: c++

There is something wrong with this C++ code. I've compiled it in VC ++ 6.0. It's giving the error "cannot deduce template argument for type"... The problem is in the `display` function.

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class type>  
struct one
{
  type data;
  one *next;
};

one<int> *head, *temp, *mid, *del = NULL;

template <class type>
void athead(type value)    
{    
  one *node = new one;    
  node->data = value;    
  node->next = head;    
  head = node;
}

template <class type>
void add_at_tail(type value)   
{
  one *node = new one;   
  node->data = value;    
  node->next = NULL;

  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = node;   
    temp = head;
  }

  while(temp->next != NULL)   
  {
    temp = temp->next;
  }

  if(temp != node)
  {
    temp->next = node;  
  }
}

template <class type>
void display()
{
  one<type> *temp = new one;
  temp = head;  
  cout << "\n\n" << endl;   
  while(temp != NULL)   
  {
    cout << " " << temp->data << " " << "->";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << "\n\n\n";
}

int main()
{
  int a, b, c;
  cout << "Enter the data: " << endl;
  cin >> a;
  add_at_tail(a);
  cout << "Enter the data: " << endl;
  cin >> b;
  add_at_tail(b);
  cout << "Enter the data: " << endl;
  cin >> c;
  add_at_tail(c);

  display();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework.  Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Couple problems here, at least:

First, you have defined the template function:

```
template<class type>
void display()
{
    one<type> *temp=new one;
    temp=head;  
    cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;   
    while(temp!=NULL)   
    {
        cout<<" "<<temp->data<<" "<<"->";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\n";
}
```

This line is malformed, because `one` is not a complete type (`one` is a class template)

```
one<type> *temp=new one;
```

You need to do this:

```
one<type> *temp=new one<type>;
```

Then down in the client code, you attempt to call the function template like this:

```
display();
```

But `display` is a function template with no arguments, so there's no way the compiler can deduce the type of it's template parameter `type`.  You must specify the type of `type` at the call point.

```
display<int>();
```

There are also logic errors with the implementation of `display()`.  You instantiate a single copy of `one` and don't initialize it.  You then try to iterate over it like it's a linked list, but it's not -- its just some uninitialized node you just created.  You probably want to pass in the linked list you're trying to iterate over.  Something along these lines:

```
template<class type>
void display(const one<type>& head)
{
    one<type> const * temp = &head;
    cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;   
    while(temp!=NULL)   
    {
        cout<<" "<<temp->data<<" "<<"->";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\n";
}
```

Now that `display` takes parameters mentioned in the template, the compiler is able to deduce its type.  You probably want to call it like this:

```
display(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a call to `display()`, but that's a template function and you've given the compiler no way to deduce the template argument. You can specify it explicitly as `display<int>();` (but the code has other problems besides that - you're writing `one` in a few places, when you should probably be writing `one<type>`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since `display()` takes no arguments, how do you think the compiler can figure out what type you expect `type` to be reified to? You could give `display()` a dummy type argument, or, better, move all these methods into a class so the type parameter can be figured out just once for the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `one *node = new one;` with `one<type>* node = new one<type>;` and altering `display();` in `main()` to `display<int>();` fixed all the compiler errors.